# Cocoa ScriptingBridge Input Polling

Tags: cocoa, input, polling, scripting-bridge

I am trying to use ScriptingBridge to write a small iTunes controller. The problem is to find an efficient way of getting notifyed whenever any changes occur. My first approch was to poll the input in a loop and just keep checking for differences. But I think there must be a more efficient way of getting notifyed about input!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes sends out a notification when something changes so just register for it in your init method of AppDelegate. Here's an example...

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivediTunesNotification:) name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" object:nil];
```

The actual notifcation object in your method "receivediTunesNotification:" will contain information about the changes.

Comment: Thanks! This works well but it is only called when the song changes but not for iTunes internal volume changes. I am using the notification for song changes now and an scheduled NSTimer for the volume display which runs smooth enough. Thanks.